# How do you un-triangulate a mesh?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I know that you can triangulate a selected portion of a mesh in *Edit Mode* by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. This converts all quads and n-gons into tris. How how can this be reversed, combining coplanar triangles into quads and n-gons?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can untriangulate the selected portion of a mesh by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. This will only create quads so some manual cleanup may be necessary if you need n-gons. You can do this by selecting the leftover edges and hitting <kbd>X</kbd> and clicking *Dissolve Edges*.

Comment: This command is also available from the 3D view menus:
Mesh > Faces > Tris to Quads

Answer (score 9):

You can use the decimate modifier using the `planar` option and apply it.
[image: decimate modifier]

Comment: This also turns them to n-gons while Alt J does not. Note that it likely won't work to set the *Angle Limit* to 0.

Comment: Note that this is the same as *Limited dissolve* in edit mode.

Comment: Note: this will most likely screw up your UV map.

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.tris_convert_to_quads()
```

Comment: One liners and code without context rarely make a good answer. Could you expand on how this helps and why?

Comment: yeah, right good feedback

Comment: Still works in 2022 on Blender 2.3.2 thanks!

Comment: This piece of code fits well if you do not want to use a modifier

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it through Blender's Python API if you want to get quads:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.tris_convert_to_quads()
```